# Return to previous uncommitted state in git

Tags: git, commit

I have a lot of files.
They are change.
I'm do commit in git.
Then I change files more and more.
But now i'm not do the commit.
Then i'm do git reset hard to previous(last) commit.

How can i return into the last uncommitted state of my folder?
(For example 10 seconds before the git reset hard)

Comment: after doing git reset --hard , files will be permanent changed....unless you have a backup repository

Comment: Devin adequately explained the problem.  I just wanted to point out that using [git stash](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) instead of reset achieves what you want in a safer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `git' [manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) it states that

```
git reset --hard
```

> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the
>   working tree since  are discarded.

If you or your editor didn't make backups it seems as if your files are gone.